# ReferenceError: $ is not defined jquery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>RateUs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\slide.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
<button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
<button class="cross">&#735;</button>
<?php
    $Title = "";
    $Description = "Say Hello to Web, cause we will make the expierience like never before From our Web Devolopment and SEO services. Way to Go!"
?>
<ul>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK ONE</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK TWO</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK THREE</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK FOUR</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK FIVE</li></a>
</ul>
</div>
</head>
</style>
<body>
    <h1><?php echo $Title ?></h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="slideImage">
        <img src="http://images.locanto.net/1650267478/Ultimez-Technology-Popular-Web-Design-Company-in-Bangalore_2.jpg" title="Long Arrow Left">
    </div>

</div>
    <p><?php echo $Description ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is html code and js code is below...

```
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".menu" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".hamburger" ).hide();
$( ".cross" ).show();
});
});

$( ".cross" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).show();
});
});
```

now the problem is it always says "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" well i also have added

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

both jquery linked libraries are not working still getting the same error please help and it is a Hamburger menu code which i took from https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/web-beginner-en-seyrq/0/1?content_from=make-an-interactive-website%3Ajquery-effectscodepen so please help i am a newbie plz do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the scripts.

`hamburgerMenu.js` has reference to jquery. When it is parsed it will look for jquery object but jQuery is not yet loaded as it comes second in loading sequence.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
```

Also to speed up the page loading you can include scripts near closing end of `body` tag

```
<body>
//rest of code
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for the help now not showing the error but still animation not working on my localhost is there any othr thing??? thank you...

Comment: thank you so much but the animation is still not working any different errors???